# How to create a cloud-based service that automatically inserts client's logo into pre-made video template and renders out as a video file?

Tags: javascript, sql, ruby-on-rails, html5-video, video-encoding

*motion graphic designer* here with only basic programming knowledge. Sorry in advance for possible inaccuracies in used terms.

Recently I stumbled upon this website called http://Viddyoze.com (link below).

Basically, it's an animation template library (templates done in Adobe After Effects). Once their client pays and upload his logo, he can choose from the offered templates, do some minor customization, such as changing of background color, and after he's done and hits RENDER button, his logo is automatically added into template of his choice and rendered out directly on websites server and then offered for download. No additional software needed.

My question is: HOW CAN I RE-CREATE WEBSITE LIKE THIS?

- (first of all) What should be relevant questions I should ask if looking for answer about how to produce website like this? (I am not a programmer)
- What's the best programming language to use for this?
- What else have to be involved in producing a website able to handle such an complex task such as rendering of the video?
- How much would typically cost to re-create something like that? Given I can produce all video templates in any format needed?

Here is the link on the website I refer to. There's a long ass sales video that you might not want to watch whole, but you get the point what's the principle of the website: 
http://viddyoze.com/private-offer/

Thank you so much! Any answer is much appreciated!

Cheers,
Mako

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html` `<canvas>` element, `HTMLMediaElement.captureStream()`, `AudioContext`, `MediaRecorder` to create video content.

See

- [Canvas recording using captureStream and mediaRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874867/canvas-recording-using-capturestream-and-mediarecorder/39886559#39886559)
- [CanvasCaptureMediaStream / MediaRecorder Frame Synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687010/canvascapturemediastream-mediarecorder-frame-synchronization/40691112#40691112)
- [Exporting a video in p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437971/exporting-a-video-in-p5-js/42455984#42455984)
- [HTML5 audio streaming: precisely measure latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768375/html5-audio-streaming-precisely-measure-latency/38842623?s=7|2.2990#38842623)
- [Synchronize video and audio (preferably without JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046644/synchronize-video-and-audio-preferably-without-javascript/39216010#39216010)